# How to build OpenSSL 1.1

Tags: windows, openssl

When OpenSSL1.1 is built by the command line on Windows 10 (x64), an error occurred.
The x86 build was successful.
What is the cause of x64 build error?
When LNK1112 occurs, it is guided how to change the target computer from the properties of the solution, but can this setting be changed by the command line?

■ Phenomenon

An error occurs in nmake after generating a makefile with perl.

Error message

```
cl  /Zi /Fdossl_static.pdb /Gs0 /GF /Gy /MD /W3 /wd4090 /nologo /O2 /I "." /I "crypto\include" /I "include" /I "crypto" -D"L_ENDIAN" -D"OPENSSL_PIC" -D"OPENSSLDIR=\"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\SSL\"" -D"ENGINESDIR=\"C:\\openssl\\build\\win\\x64\\lib\\engines-1_1\"" -D"OPENSSL_SYS_WIN32" -D"WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN" -D"UNICODE" -D"_UNICODE" -D"_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" -D"_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS" -D"OPENSSL_USE_APPLINK" -D"NDEBUG"  /Zs /showIncludes "crypto\cversion.c" 2>&1 > crypto\cversion.d
        IF EXIST .manifest DEL /F /Q .manifest
        IF EXIST libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll DEL /F /Q libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
        link /nologo /debug /dll  /nologo /debug  /implib:libcrypto.lib /out:libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll /def:libcrypto.def @C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\nm5483.tmp || (DEL /Q libcrypto-1_1-x64.* libcrypto.lib && EXIT 1)
crypto\cversion.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
```

■ Environment

VC2019

Perl v5.28.1

Build target OpenSSL 1.1.1d

■ Build command(.bat)

The same error occurs in "vcvars64.bat".

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build;%PATH%
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat"

perl Configure no-asm --prefix=C:/openssl/build/win/x64 VC-WIN64A

nmake install
```

Answer (score 0):

Was self resolved.

An error occurred when linking an x86 object because it was built with a garbage file remaining after x86 build.
The build succeeded after decompressing tgz of OpenSSL again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with building QCustomPlot2 for python. The fix was to delete the qcustomplot2 folder then decompress the tar.gz again.... The left over garbage was screwing me over no matter how I tried to build it.. I tried every developer tool for visual studio there was, even the cross compilers.. But deleting everything and then decompressing the downloader archieve was the best fix.

I have x64 windows... I used x64 native tools cmd prompt for visual studio 2019. It built perfectly first try after that.